# Best way to get the highest sum from a Matrix (using Java but algorithm is the issue here)

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Sorry I dont know the correct terminology to use but I have a 3x3 matrix like this

```
1 3 4 
5 4 5  
2 2 5
```

and I want get the highest score by picking a value from each row/column but I cant pick the same row or column more than once , so the answer in this case is

3 + 5 + 5 = 13 (row0,col1 + row1,col0 + row2,col2)

4 + 5 + 5 = 14 is not allowed because would have picked two values from col2

I'm using Java, and typically the matrix would be 15 by 15 in size.

Is there a name for what Im trying to do, and whats the algorithm

thanks Paul

EDIT:Note:the hungarian algorithm only works when no of rows equals no of cols, and in my case this is not always the case I regularly have cases of 10x12 or 11x13. But it appears
you can get round this by adding extra dummy rows.

EDIT
hmm, trying out one of these implmentations and it doesnt alwasy seem to work, unless Im misreading it

```
100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,30.0,80.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,
80.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,80.0,25.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,
80.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,25.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,
100.0,25.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,
0.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,
100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,25.0,100.0,
100.0,100.0,100.0,25.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,75.0,100.0,100.0,
100.0,80.0,30.0,100.0,75.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,
100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,80.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,25.0,
100.0,100.0,100.0,75.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,25.0,100.0,100.0,
Results calculated
0:4,0,
1:3,1,
2:7,2,
3:6,3,
4:0,4,
5:2,5,
6:1,6,
7:9,7,
8:5,8,
9:8,9,
```

Comment: The output gives you the points that were chosen, as you can see, it's in the form of `solution_nr:row,column` or `solution_nr:column,row` and the row and columns are unique as you requested ;)

Comment: Thanks KillianDS I misunderstood it, I though solution no was rowno. Does solution Nr mean anything, or it just denote the order in which the correct answer was found ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). You can look at the rows as "people" and the columns as "assignments". You want to minimise (well, you want to maximise but the idea remains) the total cost, where each person can do one task for `matrix[i][j] money`.

The [hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is a good solution, but it is fairly complicated. <strike>I think bruteforcing it will work just fine on 15x15 matrices.</strike>

Comment: +1 =) I had 15 mins to realize my mistake, and when I did, you already had an answer. Very nice.

Comment: I was just about to ask if you're sure of your answer :).

Comment: @IVlad: How would you brute force 15x15 in reasonable time, though?

Comment: Just reading the original answer which seemed to be correct to me, shows what i know !

Comment: polygenelubricants could you reinstate your links please, Ive lost them and I think do help me with a solution

Comment: @user: the keywords were "Exact cover", "Algorithm X", "Dancing Links (DLX)"; the links were all to Wikipedia articles.

Comment: ok get it now, so it is the assignment problem and there are links to Java implementations of the hungarian algorithm at the bottom of the wikipage

Comment: Yes, your best bet is the hungarian algorithm. I overestimated the brute force solution. 15! is much bigger than I thought, and there's aren't any optimization that are going to significantly speed it up. Go with the hungarian algorithm, you can definitely find java implementations.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "brute force", I guess.  If you cache you can "brute force" it, though I guess it's more like DP.

Answer (score 3):

For 15x15, you can use [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in `O(N 2^N)` time, `O(2^N)` space.  The idea is to use DP with a bitmask indicating explicitly which column is used, and implicitly which row you are up to, something like (in C):

```
/* used, cache arrays of size 1 << N, used initialized to 0 */

/* max_sum( 0, 0 ) is the starting point.  Row is implicit, but 
     here to make things easier. */
int max_sum( int row, int bitmask ) { 
      /* Base case - the number of rows */
      if ( row == num_row ) return 0;

      /* If we've already seen this bitmask */
      if ( used[ bitmask ] ) return cache[ bitmask ];
      int max_current = 0, i;

      for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
          /* If column "i" is not used */
          if ( ( bitmask & ( 1 << i ) ) == 0 )
              max_current = max( 
                             /* Use column i on this row, mark column as used
                                   on the bitmask, go on to the next row. */
                             max_sum( row + 1, bitmask | ( 1 << i ) ) 
                                 + cell[row][i],
                             max_current )

      /* Save the cache down */
      used[ bitmask ] = 1;
      return cache[ bitmask ] = max_current;
 }
```

Keep track of the precursor as necessary.  This should work up to the low 20s.

For bigger `N`s, you should consider Vlad's suggestions.

Comment: Interesting, but I struggle to follow it exactly - ever considered making a full soln available ?

Comment: It's close to the "full" solution.  I added in the memo and some additional comments.  If you're having issues, post your code?

Comment: +1 for suggesting an algorithm I suspect is less known outside of programming contest circles.

Comment: You're storing the bitmask without any row information, so in a 3x3 matrix a bitmask of 011 could mean cell[0][1] and cell[2][2] have been used, but equally that cell[2][1] and cell [1][2] have been used.  If those cells have different values, won't that give you the wrong answer?  As in:

Comment: Went away and worked through it.  Of course the bitmask is for what the best possible can be from the remaining columns, not the ones you've used, which is where I was confused.  Nice.